# 400 Parser error with Google API POST call

Tags: json, rest, meteor, google-api

I am trying to make POST call towards Search Console API. I got my example running under API Explorer, however when I try to make the same call from my meteor project, I am getting error:

> Object {error: Object} error: Object code: 400 errors: Array[1]
>   message: "Parse Error"

My code:

```
function fetchSEOForWebsite(website) {

    var call = 'webmasters/v3/sites/' + 'mdbootstrap.com' + '/searchAnalytics/query'
    var params = {
        "searchType": "web",
        "dimensions": [
            "query",
            "date",
            "page"
        ],
        "startDate": "2016-02-06",
        "endDate": "2016-02-08"
    }


    GoogleApi.post(call, {
        params: params
    }, function(error, answer) {

        console.log(answer);

    });
}
```

From Chrome console I can see POST payload:

> searchType=web&dimensions=query%2Cdate%2Cpage&startDate=2016-02-06&endDate=2016-02-08

The same query works perfectly fine from API Explorer :

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fmdbootstrap.com/searchAnalytics/query?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "searchType": "web",
 "dimensions": [
  "query",
  "date",
  "page"
 ],
 "startDate": "2016-02-06",
 "endDate": "2016-02-08"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Meteor Google Api 
https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-google-api

UPDATE:
I also checked paylod sent via API Explorer and it's different:

> {   "searchType": "web",   "dimensions":    ["query","date","page"
>   ],   "startDate": "2016-02-06",   "endDate": "2016-02-08" }

So it looks like for some reason my params are not passed as a JSON object to call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From percolate:google-api package Readme

> GoogleApi is a Google OAuth authentication wrapper around HTTP, so it
>   takes the same arguments. For example, to pass a JSON body in
>   GoogleApi.post, use:
>
> GoogleApi.post('/your/api/path', { data: jsonBody });

So I would try with `data:` instead of `params:`