# Parsing error while using the GCP Storage API to rewrite a file

Tags: javascript, rest, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have an object `sample.txt` within a bucket `mybucket` in GCP storage with content:

> My Sample content

Through a form, I would like to upload a new version of `sample.txt` in `mybucket`, overriding the existing one with new content:

> My Sample content plus plus

I would like to perform this action using the Google Cloud Platform APIs, in particular **[Objects: rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite)**.

I have then a web page with a form, as follows:

```
<form>
   <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>File input</label><input id="inputFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" class="form-control-file"/><br/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"><button id="uploadButton" type="submit" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button></div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

And a JavaScript function `submitForm()` as follows:

```
function submitForm() {
    // Read input file.
    const input = document.getElementsByName('uploadFile')[0];
    const name = input.files[0].name;
    // Call GCP storage "rewrite" API
    const uri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/' + 
    'b/mybucket' +
    '/o/' + name +
    '/rewriteTo/b/mybucket' +
    '/o/' + name;
    fetch(encodeURI(encodeURI(uri)), {
        method: 'POST',
        body: input.files[0]
    })
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log('Status: ' + res.status)
        console.log(res);
    })
}
```

However, this function returns an error message as API response body:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"parseError",
            "message":"Parse Error"
         }
      ],
      "code":400,
      "message":"Parse Error"
   }
}
```

Logging `console.log(input.files[0])`, I got:

```
file(53) {name: "sample.txt", lastModified: 1520085540064, lastModifiedDate: Sat Mar 03 2018 14:59:00 GMT+0100 (CET), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 53, …}
```

Could you please help me in understanding how to override file content with the **rewrite** API and get a new file version?

**Bonus:** how can I also add additional metadata for the new file version?

**Notes:**

- the request should be correctly authenticated and authorized.

Comment: Could you console log `name` and `input` ? And why not just overriding the old content with `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECT_NAME]` ?

Comment: @Striped the method you did mention is the `Objects: insert`. It actually works only for uploading brand-new files.

Comment: Because the endpoint you're using could only  `rename, copy, and move objects within and between buckets in Cloud Storage.` So you can't upload a new file with it.

Comment: Mmm... How could I then override an existing file providing new content?

Comment: I was searching on the official documentation here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects but without success :/ What error did you get when trying with the insert method ?

Comment: I did the same, but with no good results. This point looks a bit confusing. Hoping someone from the GCP team could give us more clarity about.

Comment: The parseError means that the request payload is wrong. To construct correct payload, you should verify everything using API Explorer first and then trace the code behavior.
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302636/400-parser-error-with-google-api-post-call

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use `insert` method instead of `rewrite`. Google Cloud Storage (GCS) [`rewrite`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite) method is used to copy a file from source bucket to destination bucket and you want to insert file to GCS from a web page. This action can be performed by `insert` method and, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert), it allows to update Metadata by editing the request body.